# windows equivalent of setting PATH in .bash_profile

Tags: windows, cmd

On UNIX, I can edit `.bash_profile` to extend the PATH variable. On Windows, I know how to edit the PATH via the GUI, but that's annoying if you're interested in automation. What I like about the UNIX approach is that it's easy to save my dotfiles and just install everything automatically with a script that copies / edits files. This is especially useful for me when I'm switching to new computers where I have to set up everything from scratch. Is there an equivalent in Windows? Anything that can be run from a shell works, I need automation, so GUIs won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
SET PATH=%PATH%; c:\Directory-to-add
```

To make a permanent PATH change

```
SETX PATH “%PATH%;C:\Directory”
```

By itself, Windows doesn’t have anything like .BASH_PROFILE, but there are a number of things you can do to get something similar.

So as not to write too long, I recommend just one:
Get a portable version of [Cmder](http://cmder.net) going.  Out of the box it comes with everything you need to set up multiple powerful dev environments easily.
It’s built on a Terminal emulator called [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io) along with many useful development tools.

Comment: Never use setx.exe to directly modify `PATH`. This is a computed variable that's the concatenation of the system and user values, so using `setx.exe "%PATH%;..."` is making a mess by storing the entire expanded and concatenated `PATH` value to the user value, which will be concatenated back with the system value when loaded. Every time you do this, you're making a bigger mess.

Comment: Instead you can create another variable named `UserPath` that can be modified via setx.exe. Append `;%UserPath%` to the user `PATH` value in the GUI environment editor. The `UserPath` value should not use `%` variables because this is the only way to ensure it's loaded before `PATH`.